# Running an app in Eclipse AVD

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, adt

I downloaded an ADT bundle for linux a few days ago and since then, I've been trying to figure out how do I load my android app project to my an AVD. I created and AVD using the AVD manager of eclipse and I'm stuck after that. 
How do I load my app to the AVD? do I have to use the "terminal"? or can I upload directly using Eclipse only.
Thanks!!

Comment: Just run the project in eclipse..Your apk will automatically be deployed and installed in the emulator..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First Clean your project such that there are no errors.
- Ensure you've your AVD up and running
- Select your project --> right Click -->Select 'Run as' --> Select --> Android Application --> This should bringup a new window which shows your AVD --> Select your AVD --> Click 'Ok'..
- You should see your app running

All the best !

Answer (score 0):

Use the Play icon in the middle.

[image]
<sub>(source: [multigesture.net](http://www.multigesture.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/runEclipse.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in both ways.

1. Eclipse: Load the project in eclise and run it. Eclipse asks whether to lauch on real device or virtual device. Select the AVD you just created and application launches in AVD.
2. If you have already built the project and have the .apk file. You can also install the apk in to AVD using terminal. Make sure AVD is running first. and type the following command in terminal.

   > > adb install filename.apk

note: In Linux the adb file is found in platform-tools directory under the SDK root directory